# In the Aria: Eclipse mission, what can I do besides releasing that crazy woman from jail?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I talked to the Eclipse leader in the C-Sec office in the Presidium Commons, but she does indeed sound very dangerous, so I chose to find another solution.

Unfortunately for me, I decided to go off and scan some solar systems instead. Now I completely forgot the content of that conversation.

What's the other solution besides releasing her?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find her second-in-command, a salarian named Sayn on level D2: *Docks: Holding Area* of the Citadel. He is in area 5: *Cargo Hold: A*. If you talk to him, you can convince him to take over as leader of Eclipse and you will gain his support.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to wait for a patch or correction code, as I'm doing now.

I agreed with your assessment of the prisoner and made the same choice.

Unfortunately, the solution involving Sayn appears to have a glitch and may not work.

I successfully convinced him to assume leadership and he happily left the cargo area, but Aria knows nothing about it and Bailey thinks I've never spoken to Sadaris, asking me to come back after I've done so.

Comment: I'm also encountering this problem.  I've been told by a friend (but haven't confirmed myself) that it will resolve once the other two leaders are taken care of.

Comment: Before you leave the holding area, Cmdr Bailey should come across your comm and tell you that the counsel has decided to keep the prisoner locked up and Aria set it up.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and have completed the Blue Suns/Blood Pack pieces. I keep coming back to the Citadel after completing missions, checking Purgatory/C-Sec Outpost/Bailey/Cargo Hold to see if anything new happens. I've had no updates yet, but I'll post back here if completing more missions moves things ahead.