# How much strength do I get from recruiting the gangs in the Citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Merc group is the best for the Aria T'Loak quests?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53966/which-merc-group-is-the-best-for-the-aria-tloak-quests)

The missions I have to do for them are questionable, and I'm a Paragon in this playthrough.

Is the benefit I get from recruiting them significant enough to betray my beliefs and morals, or can I do without them?

Comment: Do you mean War assets/military strength? Readiness is just the mulitplier

Comment: 200, as outlined here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53966/which-merc-group-is-the-best-for-the-aria-tloak-quests

Comment: You don't have to betray your beliefs, as outlined here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54924/aria-blue-suns-mission

Comment: And here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53922/in-the-aria-eclipse-mission-what-can-i-do-besides-releasing-that-crazy-woman-f

Comment: @Ben, I meant War assets -- edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you actually mean how many war assets do you receive as you can not obtain any readiness from single player whatsoever. But the answer to your question is 200:

**The Terminus Fleet** is an assortment of mercenary vessels and pirate ships bound together by little more than common geography and a fear of the Reapers. Despite this volatile mix, the Fleet seems to be functioning as one under the leadership of criminal warlord Aria T'Loak.

- Requires the completion of the three quests for Aria T'Loak
- Military Strength: 50

**The Blood Pack's** mercenaries have been compared to floods, wildfires, and other calamities. It recruits krogan and vorcha, preferably those with no regard for collateral damage. On the rare occasion when brute force is insufficient, the Blood Pack is willing to deploy weapons of mass destruction normally banned in Citadel Space.

- Requires the completion of Aria: Blood Pack
- Military Strength: 50

This "private security group" is careful to maintain its image as a professional mercenary force. In reality, the **Blue Suns** have drifted further and further into becoming a full-blown crime syndicate. Despite this, their ruthless tactics are sought after in the Terminus Systems.

- Requires the completion of Aria: Blue Suns
- Military Strength: 50

The **Eclipse Corporation** specializes in "smart" security solutions, developing tactics around surgical strikes, sabotage, and electronic warfare. These mercenaries are supported by a sizeable army of combat mechs, and rely heavily on tech for support in combat.

- Requires the completion of Aria: Eclipse
- Military Strength: 50

source- http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Alien